# Deploying my web application built using MEAN stack on the web

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-hosting

I just know that my application isn't static. 
I have used this github repository to build my application [https://github.com/jainishshah17/jainishshah.com][1]

It works perfect when i try on local host but I tried to deploy using AWS (Bitnami) and lots of other web hosting platforms but cant seem to find the right one working for me.

Can anyone tell me looking at the repository what would I need to host the app that I built?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple MEAN stack App deployment, use Heroku.

[Getting Started on Heroku with Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction)